# Increasing timeout on channel originate

Tags: asterisk, asterisk-ari

Using ARI (C#, AsterNET), I'm creating a channel via the `Originate` command:

```
   var channel = client.Channels.Originate($"SIP/{number}@{destination}", app: appName, callerId: CLI, timeout: timeout);
```

This works fine; however,`timeout` starts from when the channel is created, and in reality I'd like to timeout to only be enforced once the channel starts ringing.

Is there any way (via ARI) to manipulate the `timeout` setting once the channel is created - so I could, for example, create the channel with an arbitrary timeout, and then (re)set the timeout once the channel state has changed to `RINGING`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way do timeout based on ringing in asterisk.

Not in dialplan, not in ARI or AMI or AGI. No at all.

Only complex things like listen for event and manualy hangup channels.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using originate:

```
POST /channels
```

you could use:

```
POST /channels/create
```

to create a channel *without* dialing immediately. This allows your Stasis Application to gain control of the channel **before** it is answered.

Before `/channels/create`, you should now be setting a `StasisStart` event handler that does `/channels/dial` and sets the timeout in this request.

This won't be for *exactly* when the channel starts ringing (since that is not possible to set), but it will be *exactly* when the channel is dialed, which is hopefully pretty close to what you're looking for.

*Note*: when using this method, you will likely want to be setting the Caller ID in the `StasisStart` event handler as well, since it cannot be set in the `/channels/create` request.

Comment: For originate delay under very high load between originate placed and channel dialled  - less then 0.2 seconds. So no point go this, not add anything.

Comment: 'setting the Caller ID in the StasisStart event handler'. Wrestling with this. Care for an example?